# error: there was a problem with the editor "vi" -- while trying to edit a deployment file in a cluster

Tags: macos, kubernetes, yaml, azure-aks, vi

Facing this error **error: there was a problem with the editor "vi"** when trying to change a deployment file in the Kubernetes cluster (AKS)

`kubectl edit deploy xxxxx -o yaml`

upon exiting the file, the below error is thrown with no changes applied.

This issue occurs only when trying to edit this particular deployment. Seems to work fine for other file changes

Few screenshots...

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the size of your file? is it a long one?

Answer (score 12):

The issue is that kubectl is using vi instead of vim.

To resolve run (or add to your .bashrc or .bash_profile):

`export EDITOR=vim`

Then run your kubectl edit command.

Enjoy.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your file is a big one,

#### `set re=1`

Add this line to your `~/.vimrc` file:
`re` stands for `regex engine`

```sh
# The default is 0 so you should update it to 1
set re=1
```

You can use append to add the line:

```
# append the line the .vimrc
echo `set re=1` > ~/.vimrc
```

This will force vim to use an older version of the `regex engine` and it is should fix your problem.